# good practice managing highly related classes (class inside class)

Tags: c++, class, namespaces

Everything started simple.

I created a couple of classes. To make maintenance easier I defined a struct called `Parameters` for each class. This Parameters are changed regularly. It was easy an convenient. I could create the parameters using A::Parameters or B::Parameters, could pass them around, return them and so on... The Parameters really belonged to the specific class, but sometimes I also need them somewhere outside.

```
class A{
public:
struct Parameters{
    int a;
}
private:
Parameters para;
}

class B{
public:
struct Parameters{
    double b;
}
private:
Parameters para;
}
```

Over time my `Parameters` became more and more complex. I even started with adding some simple functions in there and soon after some more complex functions. Now they do not really feel like a structure anymore, they are more like a own class by itself. I know the difference between class and struct is very minor in C++ but I use structures mainly for raw data storage and classes for everything else.
So I decided to change them to classes:

```
class A{
public:
class Parameters{
    int a;
}
private:
Parameters para;
}

class B{
public:
class Parameters{
    double b;
}
private:
Parameters para;
}
```

Everything works well, except that it really looks a bit awkward to me. I sometimes define classes in classes but mainly as a private class and most of the time it is a very small and easy one without a lot of code. In this case here the source code becomes really messy. I would like to have a own file for these Parameter classes now.

Now I see a couple of possibilities and I cannot decide which one is the best:

- Should I create a new file `Parameters.cpp`/`Parameters.h` and store each `Parameters` class in the appropriate namespace like:

  `namespace A{ class Parameters{ int a; } }`

  `namespace B{ class Parameters{ double b; } }`

Is this then equivalent then defining the classes `Parameters` in class `A`/`B`?

- Should I create a own file for each of the classes and put the class in the namespace `A` or `B`? 
  (I would like to avoid changing the name of the `Parameter` class to `A_Parameters`, `B_Parameters` and so on... )
- Or is it somehow possible to only declare the class in A like 
  `class A{ public: class Parameters; }`
  and put the class definition somewhere else (in a different file). Note that I create instances of `Parameters` in class `A`.

I guess the main question is what is considered good practice / what would you do? One class per file, multiple namespaces in one file, rename classes...

Comment: You have not asked a specific question.  Instead this question looks like an intellectual exercise.  What is the problem your design is trying to solve?  As it stands the question is either too broad (not enough specific detail) or opinion based as there is no right answer.  Please edit your question and/or re-read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: To be clear: the difference between a class and a struct in C++ is that `struct`s are classes that use a public access specifier by default, while `class`es are classes that use a private access specifier by default.  And yes, your pattern of treating which one as having additional sigificance is common.